# adf internal error occured on executing a vo in taskflow

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

**can any body tell me the actual reason causing the below error:**

oracle.jbo.JboException: JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught: java.lang.NullPointerException, msg=null
        at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.executeQueryForCollection(ViewObjectImpl.java:7349)
        at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.execute(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1257)
        at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.executeQueryForMasters(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1449)
        at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.executeQueryForMode(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1355)
        at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.executeQuery(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1340)
        at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.executeQuery(ViewObjectImpl.java:7236)
        at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.executeIteratorBindingWithParams(DCJboDataControl.java:2987)
        at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.doIt(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:1541)
        at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControl.invokeOperation(DCDataControl.java:2150)
        at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.invoke(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:740)
...
...
..
.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectAtName(OraclePreparedStatement.java:15884)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObjectAtName(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:911)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObjectAtName(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.jbo.server.OracleSQLBuilderImpl.bindParamValue(OracleSQLBuilderImpl.java:4669)
        at oracle.jbo.server.BaseSQLBuilderImpl.bindParametersForStmt(BaseSQLBuilderImpl.java:3687)
        at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.bindParametersForCollection(ViewObjectImpl.java:22684)

Comment: Where is this error coming from?  Oracle itself? Your code?  If the first, you may want to try SuperUser or possibly(?) DBA stackexchanges, but if your code please include your code.

Comment: Hi, This error is not from the code. at server i face this exception intermittantly. many of the times my code woks, but sometime i face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace, it seems some bind variable that is required by your view object query is not being set correctly. 
If it works intermittently, it could be that the bind variable is lost at some point. To debug/test, try it with a hard-coded value for your bind variable and see if that works first (if you have a ViewCriteria, try removing that first) - then run the task flow and see if it works consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running the application in JDeveloper with -Djbo.debugoutput=console argument. It gives you a lot if information of what your business components are doing and you could catch the error cause in console logs.